# Mysql Select records that not contain records of second table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 MySQL tables with 1 column and a lot of records. I should select records of the first table that doesn't CONTAIN rows of second table.
Can anyone help me with a query?

```html
Table 1:
http://www.google.com
http://www.aaaa.com
http://bbbb.com
http://www.cccc.com
http://www.dddd.com

Table 2:
tttt.com
aaaa.com
google.com
rrrr.com
dddd.com

Result should to be:
http://bbbb.com
http://www.cccc.com
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a `left join` and `like`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.col like concat('%', t2.col, '%')
where t2.col is null;
```

Unfortunately, you cannot use indexes to optimize this query, so the engine will have to do a nested loop join.

Comment: you are the God of MySQL :)

Answer (score 0):

Works!!
A question: why the last row "where t2.col is null" ?

Regards